# to offset image in the backgorund

Tags: html, css

I know the css very bad. I need  some help.
I have div with other elements:

```
<div class="place_section" style="height:375px;" data-session="3" data-client="2">
   <div class="row">1</div>
     <div id="3" class="place place_type1" data-place="[l=1;f=0;r=1;p=1]">
       <div class="center_chair">
         <span class="left_chair"></span>
         <span class="right_chair"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
   // other divs
</div>
```

This is the `css`:

```
.place_section {
    background: url("/content/images/screen_bg.png") 0 0 repeat-x;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

This is screenshot how it looks:
[image]

I want to offset image (blue line) to the right, approximately on 20-25px. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You want 4 number line to move right hand side a bit?

Comment: No, the main(root) div have the backgound (blue line in the top) and I want to offset it to the right.

Comment: Your margin-top was supposed to be margin-right i guess because you are using margin:0 auto (which means 0 from top) then why you are giving margin-top:40px again?

Comment: I commented `margin:0 auto` and trying to play with margin-left, but then all div move, but I want only image.

Comment: it would be nice if we can see your code in jsfiddle or else where.

Comment: apply left:25px else try background: url("/content/images/screen_bg.png") 0px 20px repeat-x;

Comment: `0px 20px` to offset by `y` coordinate. I tryed `20px 0px` but nothing changes.

Comment: cant we see a running problem it hard to tell you like this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I'd add a div before row1 to represent the screen:

```
<div class="place_section">
  <div class="big_screen">
  <div class="row"> ... </div>
  <div class="row"/>... </div>
</div>
```

This will afford you far more flexibility when styling the big_screen:

```
.big_screen {
  background: url("/content/images/screen_bg.png") 0 0 repeat-x;    
  margin: ...;    
}
```

Hope it helps.